# Celery Flower dashboard remove worker

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, flower

I recently installed flower 0.8.4, I created an snapshot in Digital Ocean and then launch a new server using this snapshot. Now flower is still showing the name of the old worker. How can I delete this worker while preserving existing worker information.

Celery starts:

```
worker -n celeryd@%h -f /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log --loglevel=DEBUG --autoscale=50,10
```

Flower:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower --basic_auth=root:password --port=8082 --broker=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq:5672// --persistent=True --db=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/flower.db
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched off the persistent Flag from True to False and restart celery.

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower --basic_auth=flower:flower --port=8082 --broker=amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@rabbitmq:5672// --inspect=True --persistent=True --db=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/flower.db
```

Answer (score 10):

A new option purge_offline_workers (`--purge_offline_workers` / `FLOWER_PURGE_OFFLINE_WORKERS`) has been recently added to flower. This option removes offline workers from the flower dashboard.

For more information please refer to https://github.com/mher/flower/pull/852   and https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/604

Moreover, the latest version of mher/flower has a search box on the top right corner of the dashboard. By typing the word `online` in the search box you can filter out all offline workers.